# Placeholder checking works in some cases, and in some don't

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am making some app (Turing machine simulator) and i have few textfields in my FirstViewControler. I have made it to be delegate for those textFields and i diferentiate between them by checking their Placeholder text as you can see from the code. It was alright and working with those bottom textfields (see image) for entering functions into tableview, but when i added SegmentedView and TextField at the top, and i wanted to instantly update segmented view as person typed in the field, it somehow doesn't recognise placeholder of that textField ("0." was added jut to test it, it was "Enter number here").

So in short, those first 5 ifs are working and doing their job, but the last one with == "0." check - is not working and i can't figure out why.

[This is my storyboard and document outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLk1n.png)

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string.characters.count > 0 {

                    // za prvi: 0..9
        if textField.placeholder == "0..9" {

            switch string {
            case "0": return true
            case "1": return true
            case "2": return true
            case "3": return true
            case "4": return true
            case "5": return true
            case "6": return true
            case "7": return true
            case "8": return true
            case "9": return true
            default: return false
            }
        }
        // za drugi
        else if textField.placeholder == "0/1/b" {

            switch string {
            case "0": return true
            case "1": return true
            case "b": return true
            default: return false
            }
        }
        // za treci
        else if textField.placeholder == "0..9/+/-" {

            switch string {
            case "0": return true
            case "1": return true
            case "2": return true
            case "3": return true
            case "4": return true
            case "5": return true
            case "6": return true
            case "7": return true
            case "8": return true
            case "9": return true
            case "+": return true
            case "-": return true
            default: return false
            }
        }
        // za cetvrti
        else if textField.placeholder == "0/1/b " {

            switch string {
            case "0": return true
            case "1": return true
            case "b": return true
            default: return false
            }
        }
        // za peti
        else if textField.placeholder == "+/-" {

            switch string {
            case "+": return true
            case "-": return true
            default: return false
            }
        }
        else if textField.placeholder == "0." {
            if ((string == "0") || (string == "1")) {
                traka.append(Character(string))
                osveziTraku()
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
        else {
            return true
        }

    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not see any problem in your code, I just refactored it a bit, It might solve your problem.

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string.characters.count > 0 {

        switch textField.placeholder
        {
        case "0..9", "0..9/+/-", "+/-", "0/1/b" :

            switch string {
            case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",  "+", "-", "b": return true
            default: return false
            }
        case "0." :

            switch string {
            case "0", "1":
                traka.append(Character(string))
                osveziTraku()
                return true
            default: return false
            }
        default : return false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```